# LDAP & RPC Causing A/D Issues

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, rpc

Having an issue with authentication on my network. Running Windows Server 2008 R2

**Layout**:

Network is a non internet connected network using DCs running DNS/AD/File Sharing. NO DHCP all addresses are Static. DNS is pointing to DC1 & DC2.

**Working**

File sharing is working as if you do a \DC to it will show shares as well as shares on the rest of the network.

**Problem**
When connected to the network machines say "unidentified network" not the domain. Secondly when I try to add machines to the domain it says it cannot reach the domain. Also users cannot login to it as it says no login servers exist.

Ran a DCDIAG on the DC1 itself and got

```
Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity
```

All ports for LDAP and RPC are allowed and the firewall is off.

While running DCDIAG /TEST:DC I got this.

```
NO LDAP CONNECTIVITY
Warning Adpapter
Invalid DNS Server
No host records (A) or (AAA) were found on this DC
NO DNS RPC connectivity

PTR Record query for the *** failed on the DNS Server
Name resolution is not functional
```

I have been working on this all week and it is driving me crazy. Do I need to backup my entire A/D and redo it or am I missing something I don't understand here. I can't add machines to the domain and network accounts will not login and all machines say they are on an "unidentified network".

At this point I have only the DC on and 1 computer. The DC says it is connected to the Domain but the computer say it isn't. I can Remote to the DC by name. Not sure what to do at this point.

**UPDATE:1**
After adding a system account and service account to the security groups for file replication and one for certificate access which allows the machines to see the domain. CURRENTLY STILL GETTING LDAP and RPC connectivity issue which is preventing the machines from joining the domain. Login servers seem to be working atm but still cannot add machines to the domain. Is there a way to rebuild or reconnect LDAP?

Comment: Does the server have multiple network adapters?

Comment: @RyanRies yes but I am only using 1. All others are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP zone msdcs_domian.com.com was missing from zone. When drive crashed and windows did a checkdisk it must have rebuilt the file with the missing msdcs.

Comment: I suggest to elaborate more your answer (best if you explain, _why_ is it).